# cross-platform dynamic terminal printing

Tags: python-3.x, output, stdout

Consider this code:

```
import time

while True:
    print(f"{object}")
    doing_something_to_object(object)
    object.update()
    time.sleep(3)
```

output would look like this, making newline:

```
value
value
value
value
```

I want to do something so that when `object` is ready to be displayed, `object` *updates* on the screen.

For better explanation,

i want to output a screen with consistently updated values.:

```
*--------------------------------------*

value1                          value2

*--------------------------------------*
```

if i was to print that in a loop, updating values in string before next print, it would look like this (i don't want this):

```
*--------------------------------------*

value1                          value2

*--------------------------------------*
*--------------------------------------*

value1                          value2

*--------------------------------------*
*--------------------------------------*

value1                          value2

*--------------------------------------*
*--------------------------------------*

value1                          value2

*--------------------------------------*
```

what are some ways to do this without using something like pygame or tkinter? `curses` should do the trick, but it is not cross-platform. is there something `curses` for both linux and windows?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to update the value where it is displayed, without printing it again below it...

In terminal/CLI windows (all of them as far as I know), once a line has been printed, it can't be modified or erased - everything before the current prompt/output line is read-only text.
*But you can still change the line you're currently on*, the method of doing that is

1. Don't print a newline (`\n`) character till you're done, and
2. Use the carriage-return (`\r`) to shift the cursor to the start of the line, so the next values get written "on top" of the previous

Note that the "\r" is *not* backspacing, for example `print("abcdefg\rxyz")` would result in `xyzdefg`. Pad the text with spaces as you need.

```py
import time

t1 = time.time()
obj = 0

while obj < 100000000:
    obj = time.time() - t1
    print(f"\r{obj}", end='')
    time.sleep(0.5)

print("\nDone !")
```

Comment: right. `curses` is best for my situation. only problem is it's not cross-platform.